# Video tagging on facebook via ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

How to tag a our facebook friends in a video using facebook api and ios sdk ..

Please suggest me the right way to do the same...
Thanks in advance .. abhishek..

Comment: did you found a way to tag friends in your video? because I have this problem and I can't find any solution